# Understanding Ruby class vs instance methods

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

class Person
  def self.speak
    p = self.new
    puts "Hello"
    p.chatter
  end

private

  def chatter
    puts "Chattering"
  end
end

p = Person.new
Person.speak
```

I'd like to make chatter private, accessible only within p.. but I want p to be able to access it within the class method. Is there a better way to design this so chatter isn't available to the public, but a "factory" method like self.speak can call chatter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8.7, "send" bypasses the usual protections against calling private methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

class Person

  def self.speak
    puts "Hello"
    new.send(:chatter)
  end

  def speak
    puts "Hello"
    puts chatter
  end

  private

  def chatter
    puts "Chattering"
  end

end

Person.speak        # => Hello
                    # => Chattering
Person.new.speak    # => Hello
                    # => Chattering
```

However, what you want can be achieved without any voodoo, by simply having the class method do all the work, and the instance method defer to the class method:

```
class Person

  def self.speak
    puts "Hello"
    puts "Chatter"
  end

  def speak
    self.class.speak
  end

end
```

If you had more than a few of these forwarding methods, it might be convenient to make a helper method that makes them for you:

```
module DelegateToClass

  def delegate_to_class(name)
    define_method(name) do |*args|
      self.class.send(name, *args)
    end
  end

end

class Person

  extend DelegateToClass

  def self.speak
    puts "Hello"
    puts "Chatter"
  end
  delegate_to_class :speak

end
```

The built-in module `Forwardable` can do this just as well:

```
require 'forwardable'

class Person

  extend Forwardable

  def self.speak
    puts "Hello"
    puts "Chatter"
  end

  def_delegator self, :speak

end
```

`def_delegator` also bypasses protections against private methods.

Comment: Nice solution, although I have the feeling that if the OP has to resort to such tricks, there is something much more fundamentally wrong with the design.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, I agree.  It may be a sign that the method really out to move out, get a job, and settle down in its own module or class.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways to do this.  One approach would be a class method which instantiates a new instance and calls the `#speak` method on the instance.

```
class Person
  def self.speak
    new.speak
  end

  def speak
    puts "Hello"
    chatter
  end

  private

  def chatter
    puts "Chattering"
  end
end
```

Then you could call it in either the class or instance context:

```
p = Person.new
p.speak
# ...or...
Person.speak
```